# Redirection using ajax

Tags: ajax

I am trying to redirect to a page after successful ajax.  Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "blogdelete.jsp",
    data: val,
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    success: function (msg) {
        window.location.href="hodlogin.jsp";
    }
});
```

This is not working. Any suggestions??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Define "not working."  Is the AJAX request being made?  Is the server responding with an expected response?  Is the success handler invoked?  What *actually happens* when you run this code?

Comment: everything is working.The server is responding correct result.Only the page is not getting redirected to "hodlogin.jsp". This is the problem.And yes the success handler is getting invoked.I have tested that.

Comment: have you tried just `window.location = "hodlogin.jsp"`

Comment: yes i have tried that too..not working either

Answer (score 1):

Seems success block not executing.
You must add error block to check any errors or use browser console.

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "blogdelete.jsp",
data: val,

async: true,
cache: false,
success: function (msg) {

console.log('success');
alert('success');                            
         },
error: function(){
console.log('error');
alert('error');
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by putting an alert (or break point in firebug) inside of the success function to be 100% sure its being called. If it is then I would try these options:

```
var url = "hodlogin.jsp";
window.location = url;
```

Or

```
$(location).attr("href", url);
```

If those still fail and you are sure there being called then double check your url. Maybe its not in the same directory as the javascript that is calling the window.location. You could try an absolute path in that case just to see if it works.

Comment: thanx mate.By defining a var url and then setting its value to window.location is working.Thank you very much :)